# MATLAB: Compare matrices built with repelem and repmat

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have an array a of size ZxW.

```
Z = 20;
W = 30;
A = 40; %will be used below
size(a)
20      30
```

Then I apply to a two different transformations, and then after those I delete a and I cannot go back to it.

First transformation:

```
b = repelem(a(:,1),A,A);
```

Second transformation:

```
c = repmat(a,[1,1,A,A]);
d = c(:,1,:,:);
```

After those transformations and deleting a (which cannot be used for the following), I want to compare d and b using

```
assert( isequal(b,f) )
```

Where f is a transformation of d that makes the assertion true.

My first idea was a simple reshape:

```
f = reshape(squeeze(d),[Z*A,A]);
```

Which does not work as repelem and repmat move entries differently. How can I do this?

Thanks for the attention.

Sincerely

Luca

EDIT: changed

```
c = repmat(a,[A,A]);
```

with

```
c = repmat(a,[1,1,A,A]);
```

Comment: You can edit your posts for corrections, instead of deleting and reposting, in future. I'm reposting the answer I added to the original post again here.

Comment: Btw, since `c` is a 2D array (as `a` is a 2D array), you can just have `d = c(:, 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @crazyGamer, I will remember for the future.

Comment: Sure :). Also, did my solution work? Or are you expecting something else?

Comment: With the changed text the answer is different from yours; luckily also Jan Simon helped. Thanks @crazyGamer for your time.

Comment: You're welcome, do accept whichever answer helped you best, to close this question formally.

Comment: And that should be the one from Jan Simon.

Answer (score 1):

The answer (by Jan Simon) is:

```
f = reshape(permute(d, [3,1,4,2]), [Z*A,A]);
isequal(b, f)    % 1: equal
```

Thanks for the help.

Luca

Answer (score 0):

#### NOTE: This solution is obsoleted with the edited question, please refer to the other solutions posted.

Look closely at what the pattern of `b` and `d` are:

```
b = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3].'
d = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3].'
```

#### Hence, the transformation `f` can be:

```
f = reshape(d, [A, A]).'
f = f(:)
```

This will convert `d` to be exactly `b` or vice versa.